# When to use probabilistic schemes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> I have a box with $10$ bulbs, from which $3$ are broken. We randomly pick $2$ of them. What is the probability that at least $1$ bulb is broken?

I think here we could use the Bernoulli probabilistic scheme, but I'm not sure how to use it, and why it should be used here, and why we need to use probabilistic schemes?

Comment: Bernoulli, or binomial, processes rely on the trials being independent.  That's not the case here.  Drawing an unbroken one first increases the probability that the second one is broken.

Comment: I dont really know a lot about probability theory, but I think the tag "schemes" is missused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by means of [hypergeometric distribution](http://This%20can%20be%20solved%20[hypergeometric%20distribution]) and gives outcome:$$\frac{\binom31\binom71}{\binom{10}2}+\frac{\binom32\binom70}{\binom{10}2}=\frac8{15}$$

More directly you can find the probability as: $$1-P(\text{no bulb is broken})=1-P(\text{first not broken})P(\text{second not broken}\mid\text{first not broken})=$$$$1-\frac7{10}\frac69=\frac8{15}$$

Answer (score 1):

We find the probability none of them are broken. Indeed, there are $7 \choose 2$ ways to do so out of $10 \choose 2$ choices. So the probability of this is $\frac{{7 \choose 2}}{{10 \choose 2}}$, and so the probability at least one is broken is $1-\frac{{7 \choose 2}}{{10 \choose 2}}$.

Comment: yeah, but how would I do this using some kind of probabilistic scheme?

Comment: @drhab Thanks, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the first bulb isn't replaced, then

no. of ways of selecting 2 unbroken bulbs = $^7C_2 = 21$

Total ways of selecting any 2 bulbs = $^{10}C_2 = 45$

So, probability of selecting 2 unbroken bulbs = $\frac{21}{45}=\frac{7}{15}$

$P(\text{ at least one bulb is broken } ) = 1-\frac{7}{15} = \frac{8}{15}$[ as mentioned by @auscrypt].

---

2) Required cases - possible {GB, BB, BG}

G - good, B- broken

$(i)$  $P_1 = \frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9} = \frac{7}{30}$

$(ii)$ $P_2 = \frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9} = \frac{1}{15}$

$(ii)$ $P_3 = \frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{10} = \frac{7}{30}$

Total probability = $P_1+P_2+P_3 = \frac{8}{15}$

Answer (score 0):

There are three successful outcomes for at least one broken. These are:
$BU, UB$ and $BB$.

We can easily compute the probability of each outcome whereby the "sum" is the probability that at least one is broken.

$P(B>0) = P(BU)+P(UB)+P(BB)$

$P(BU) = \frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{7}{9} =  \frac{7}{30}$

$P(UB) = \frac{7}{10}\cdot {3}{9} = \frac{7}{30}$

$P(BB) = \frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9} = \frac{1}{15}$

$P(B>0) = \frac{7}{30}+\frac{7}{30}+\frac{1}{15} = \frac{8}{15}$

This is also equal to $1 - P(UU) = 1 - \frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9} = 1 - \frac{7}{15} = \frac{8}{15}$